# What DVC does when git merge is executed?

Tags: git, dvc

I have two git branches (master and develop). DVC maps a data folder in both of them. When I go into master and merging with develop is correct that DVC does not add any new file inside the data folder created in the develop branch but leaves the folder as it is unchanged?

Answer (score 3):

If the tracked directories have different contents, the merge will have conflicts in `.dvc` (and/or `dvc.lock`) files. There's an official document on how to address this situation: https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/how-to/merge-conflicts

TL;DR: merge the dataset manually and `dvc commit` the folder.